# How to return array list as a python object?

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I have a method which sends a message to Facebook in [Generic template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template) .
My code:

```
def send_receipt(self, fbid, title, url, img_url, summary):
    return self._send(message={
        "recipient": {
            "id": fbid
        },
        "message": {
            "attachment": {
                "type": "template",
                "payload": {
                    "template_type": "generic",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "title": title,
                            "item_url": url,
                            "image_url": img_url,
                            "subtitle": summary
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

It works fine for me, but it only returns 1 element. I want to get 2 or 3 elements from JSON, so I think that I can make it work by making an element object, and this object returns the array list.

```
def send_receipt(self, fbid, elements):
    return self._send(message={
        "recipient": {
            "id": fbid
        },
        "message": {
            "attachment": {
                "type": "template",
                "payload": {
                    "template_type": "generic",
                    "elements": elements
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

And I did make a method to return elements. But I'm new to python, so what I have done didn't work for me.

```
elements = [{
            "title": title,
            "item_url": url,
            "image_url": img_url,
            "subtitle": summary }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is making a method which converts the result to a list elements

```
temp = []
for index, product in enumerate(products):
    element = {'title': title,
               'subtitle': sumary,
               'item_url': item_url}
    #not every product has image_url so to prevent KeyError, I have a if
    if 'image_url' in product:
        element['image_url'] = image_url
    temp.append(element)
    # In Facebook API element is limited to 10
    if index == 9:
       break
return temp
```